# Integrate a url in an NFT during the mint

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft, blockchain

I would like to add the possibility when I mint an NFT to integrate a "URL" in the parameters of the NFT.
For this I tried to modify my mint function in my smart contract like this:

```
@sp.entry_point
def mint(self, params):
        mint_params = sp.TList(
            sp.TRecord(
                to_=sp.TAddress,
                metadata=sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes),
                url=sp.TString,
            )
        )
        c = sp.contract(mint_params, self.data.token, entry_point="mint").open_some()
    
        args = [sp.record(
            to_=sp.sender,
            metadata={'': params.metadata},
            url=params.url)]
        sp.transfer(args, sp.mutez(0), c)
    
        
        self.data.data[self.data.token_id] = sp.record(
            holder=sp.sender,
            author=sp.sender,
            amount=params.amount,
            token_id=self.data.token_id,
            collectable=True)
        self.data.token_id += 1
```

And here is my test:

```
marketplace.mint(
        amount=sp.tez(100),
        metadata=sp.pack(
            "ipfs://bafyreibwl5hhjgrat5l7cmjlv6ppwghm6ijygpz2xor2r6incfcxnl7y3e/metadata.json"),
        url="https://example.com"
    ).run(sender=admin, valid=False, exception="FA2_NOT_ADMIN")
    token_contract.set_administrator(marketplace.address).run(sender=admin)
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Error: Error in Scenario
Wrong or unsupported exception matching (expected failure in transaction)
Wrong type for contract(0).
(sp.contract(sp.TList(sp.TRecord(metadata = sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes), to_ = sp.TAddress, url = sp.TString).layout(("metadata", ("to_", "url")))), self.data.token, entrypoint='mint') : sp.TOption(sp.TContract(sp.TList(
        {
          metadata: sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes);
          to_: sp.TAddress;
          url: sp.TString;
        }.layout(("metadata", ("to_", "url")))))))
sp.TList(
  {
    metadata: sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes);
    to_: sp.TAddress;
  }.layout(("to_", "metadata")))
instead of
sp.TList(
  {
    metadata: sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes);
    to_: sp.TAddress;
    url: sp.TString;
  }.layout(("metadata", ("to_", "url"))))
Please set a stable type.
(__main__, line 35)
Received:'Wrong type for contract'
Expected:'FA2_NOT_ADMIN'
(__main__, line 128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sp.string` type cannot contain `/` and is not suited for URLs.

Instead you can use the `sp.bytes` type.

That said, the URL should probably be included in the metadata.
So I suggest you not to modify your mint entrypoint and include your URL in the metadata.

The bytes value is the hexadecimal encoding equivalent to this in Python:

```
"0x" + s.encode('utf-8').hex()
```